# Reading an RSS feed in vb.net, the rss feed is php

Tags: xml, vb.net, rss, xmlreader

Sorry about the title I didn't quite know how to phrase it. I have scoured for code examples to read RSS feeds, however they seem to only read RSS if it is XML: mywebsite.com/myfeed.xml, How would I go about reading a feed such as this one: http://www.tvrage.com/myrss.php The myrss is PHP and the XML reader does not like it.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do realize that the actual content of the file is in XML format?
The file literally starts with:
 `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

If you are programming the RSS reader yourself, then just read it as a stream.